# High throughput logging architecture with .NET and SQL Server

Tags: .net, performance, t-sql, logging

I need to log requests made to a family of sites. Current volumes of traffic are 100s of requests a minute, but this will only increase.

There are two types of request, "known" and "unknown" - determined by the presence of a cookie.

Ultimately I want to end up with logs in the following form:

For unknowns:

- # of hourly visits per site

For knowns:

- # of hourly visits per site
- # of visits per user
- # last visit time of each user

What would be your recommendations for storing this?

The writes need to be super fast, so I'm guessing just dump all the data into a raw table and parse it periodically with a separate process/thread.

However, whats the best way to "parse" the raw data, without locking the table while the data is removed; thus blocking writes?

N.B. I'm not asking for the aggregating SQL, rather tips and procedures on how to keep it fast, not block writes, anything else i havent thought of.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First: I read that you are looking specifically for SQL answers. However i think personally that it will not be the solution you are looking for.

Systems like [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) with features like [Map/Reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) are especially meant to handle this case of data. There are various blog posts see e.g.

[Hadoop and Log File Analysis](http://www.lexemetech.com/2008/01/hadoop-and-log-file-analysis.html) or this [Log Analysis and Incident Reporting with Hadoop](http://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/log-analysis-and-incident-reporting-with-hadoop/)

Some advantages:

- scaling Hadoop is much more cheap than with RDBMS
- the aggregation can be distributed over many machines
- map/reduce has no need for a predefined strucutre. Thus you will not be that doomed if there are requirement changes

If you stick with a SQL database you will run at some point in problems like:

- Scaling RDBMs in a horizontal way costs time in aggregation in most cases. It is not in any case possible to scale horizontally.
- Aggregations are solely fast from a performance perspective if you have a well defined structure and aggregate on one or multiple indexes
- You need to transform your model with heavy operations while changing data structure